# Count occurrence in one variable based on another when having duplicated values

Tags: r, group-by, count, summarize

I know there are so many threats answering similar questions to mine but none of the answers out there are specific enough to what I want to obtain.

I've got the following dataset:
[image: table description]

I want to count the number of patients (found in "Var_name") that harbour each mutation (found in "var_id") and display the count in a new column ("var_freq"). I've tried things like:

```
y <- ALL_merged %>%
  group_by(var_id, Var_name) %>%
  summarise(n_counts = n(), var_freq = sum(var_id == Var_name))
```

NOTE: In case is relevant for the answers... I had to convert "var_id" and "Var_name" into characters to make this work because they were factors.

However, this does not give me the output I want. Instead, I get the count of how many times each "var_id" appear per patient since, for each "var_id", the same "Var_name" appears a lot of times (because rows contain additional columns with different information), so the final outcome gives me a higher count that I would expect:

[image]

I also want to add this new column to the original dataset, I believe this could be done for example by using "mutate". But not sure how to set up everything...

So, in sum, what I want to get is: for each "var_id" how many different "Var_name" I have - taking into account that these data is duplicated...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Images are not helpful. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you are looking for. It would help to provide data without images (such as using `dput`) and clearly show what your output should be for example data.

Based on what you describe this might be helpful. First, `group_by` just `var_id` alone. Then in `summarise`, you can include `n()` to get the number of observations/rows of data for each `var_id`, and then `n_distinct` to get the number of unique `Var_name` for each `var_id`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(var_id) %>%
  summarise(n_counts = n(), 
            var_freq = n_distinct(Var_name))
```